# RefineryCMS app creation problem in Windows XP

Tags: ruby-on-rails, refinerycms

I'm having real problems getting refinerycms to work on Windows. I have got the installation working correctly on a Windows 7 machine at work and have copied the set-up for home, but I just get this error every time I try and create a new app.

```
$ refinerycms testapp --heroku
c:/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/refinerycms-1.0.8/bin/refinerycms:444:in ``': N
o such file or directory - cmd /c " "c:\Ruby\bin\ruby" -S  rails --version " (Er
rno::ENOENT)
    from c:/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/refinerycms-1.0.8/bin/refinerycms:
444:in `run_command'
    from c:/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/refinerycms-1.0.8/bin/refinerycms:
173:in `validate!'
    from c:/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/refinerycms-1.0.8/bin/refinerycms:
135:in `run!'
    from c:/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/refinerycms-1.0.8/bin/refinerycms:
468:in `<top (required)>'
    from c:/Ruby/bin/refinerycms:19:in `load'
    from c:/Ruby/bin/refinerycms:19:in `<main>'
```

I'm really lost now as what to do. Just wish I had a mac to work on!

Any help much appreciated.

Comment: Can you please try running the command manually to see which part of it is failing?  It is effectively trying to run "rails --version" but we prepend your ruby binary because that is the convention.

Comment: Thanks, but I'm not 100% sure how I do that. If by running it manually you mean to put the full path in, then I've tried that and it returns the same results. Sorry if I'm being stupid, but I'm new to Rails.